# content has space in left and right side of page after adding wrap div for footer purpose?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added wrap div in order to make sticky footer, this work successfully, however a new problem just appeared, page content moved to center instead of maintaining in assigned position. The space is occurred from left and right side equally and you will notice that when page maximized.

How to remove the space from left and right side and make `wrap` div has full width?

code:

```
 <div id="wrap">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">

  </nav>
<!--*********************body*****************************-->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>

    <div id="map-container" class="col-md-4 div-head"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
     </div>
     <br > <br >
      <div  class="col-md-6 div-head">
         <p>


        </p>
     </div>
</div>
  </div><!-- end wrap-->
 <!-- footer div -->
  <div id="footer">
       <div class="container">
         <p>
            <i class="fa fa-copyright"></i>Footer
         </p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Always post relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: I have tried that but space still there...try to maximize the working fiddle and you will watch that

Comment: I am not getting you really.

Comment: actually, after adding `wrap`div the body content aligned with space from right and left...I want to remove the space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class `container-fluid` instead of `container` in

```
<div class="container">
```

Answer (score 0):

for the full width of div inside body **`container-fluid`** instead of **`container`**.

Both `.container` and `.container-fluid` are responsive (i.e. they can change based on the screen width), but in different ways. It's a common misconception that only container-fluid is responsive.

**From a functional perspective:**

`.container-fluid` continuously resizes as you change the width of your window/browser by any amount, leaving no extra empty space on the sides ever, unlike how .container does. (Hence the naming: "fluid" as opposed to "digital", "discrete", "chunked", or "quantized").

`.container` resizes in chunks at several certain widths. In other words, it will be a specific aka "fixed" width at different screen widths.

You can see how naming confusion may arise. Technically, we can say .container is "fixed width" as opposed to "fluid" because width is a specific value at a given screen width range. But of course that "fixed" width changes to another "fixed" width value. So people may get the impression that .container can't change sizes and is thus not responsive when they hear (or when you say) `.container` is "`fixed width`". So if you want to communicate this clearly to someone new, you can say something like, "`.container` makes it fixed width for a given screen width range, but can still be responsive."

**From a fundamental perspective:**

`.container-fluid` has the CSS property `width: 100%;`, so it continually readjusts at every screen width granularity.

```
.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
}
```

`.container` has something like `"width = 800px" (or em, rem etc.)`, a specific pixel width value at different screen widths. This of course is what causes the element width to abruptly jump to a different width when the screen width crosses a screen width threshold. And that threshold is governed by CSS3 media queries, which allow you to apply different styles for different conditions, such as screen width ranges.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
  .container {
    width: 123px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px){

  .container {
    width: 456px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px){
  .container {
    width: 789px;
  }
}
```

**Beyond**

You can make any fixed widths element responsive via `media queries`, not just `.container` elements. In fact, media queries is exactly how `.container` is implemented by bootstrap in the background